# Water spots on screen after liquid got in iPhone 6, fixable?

Tags: iphone, screen, damage

**Issue:** The ringer on/off switch on my iPhone 6 was stuck/gummed up so I sprayed it with contact cleaner. I didn't think liquid could get in through that opening, but I was extremely dumb. iPhone was off, waited overnight before powering on. Major waterspotting on screen. Rice trick got rid of most of it, but some spots remain. iPhone works 100%, except my battery life took a nose dive after, surely related. I'm about to replace the battery (which I've done before; iPhone is way past warranty).

**While I'm in there replacing the battery, how do I also fix this waterspot issue?**

I was thinking I might be able to wipe the liquid spots off with alcohol after reaching steps 37-41 in this iFixit guide: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6s+Front+Panel+Replacement/56283

Two pictures of current state here on GDrive. I could live with it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OnUqyyuLHVz2ahBBqVt2TLEsM13_VhyH/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ahYU2YGUUUepffWd47mwV32_fmFd1Rtd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can swap the LCD and battery while you’re in there. Up to you if you want to replace more like the digitizer.

I’d live with it for as long as you can until you determine if the contact fluid will corrode anything else or if you won’t use the phone for another 13 months.

Comment: Thanks Bmike. I think you're saying I'd have to buy a replacement screen. I was hoping you'd say "just dissemble to point X and wipe it with alcohol." Sounds like that's a nope. I'll live with it. Thanks for taking the time to answer.